# What is State 126 for Error Number 18456 on Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem logging into a Azure SQL Database from SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual Studio 2015. I'm getting the normal 18456 login error number but I can't find a reference to State 126. Anyone know what this state means?

Oddly enough I can get a connection using LinqPad on the same machine so I'm pretty sure it's not an Azure SQL Server firewall thing.

Here's the message I get (part of the error detail):

```
Error Number: 18456
Severity: 11
State: 126
Line Number: 65536
```

Answer (score 0):

Error 18456 state 126 means that the database requested by the user does not exist. I'd suggest clicking the Options button in the connection dialog to expose additional connection options, and verifying that the Connection Properties tab has a "Connect to database" value of default selected. Then, ensure that the Additional Connection Parameters box is empty.

Comment: aha I see, do you have a reference link for that? I just couldn't find that particular state documented.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I looked it up in a Microsoft Internal doc.